# BIRT: Number type (formats) hell

Tags: java, localization, locale, birt

Birt supports 3 number/digits types (e.g. for output columns in dataset):

- `Integer`
- `Decimal`
- `Float`

At the same time, BIRT has the only 1 (yes! ONE!!!) css build-in format for numbers. That means if you have, for instance int (days) and decimal (amounts) you can't use build-in css style for them (you have define own and apply them on each item).

Go further. You call Java class from BIRT and pass to it so called `Integer` value. What you get at Java? Correct `Double`. At it's no way to now at that level that originally we have `Integer` value.

Of course in some cases you could try to guess data type based on a value. 
E.g.

```
    public Object formatFromBirt(Object pObject){
    if (pObject == null) return null;
    ...
    if (pObject instanceof Double) {
        // workaround for int as double (e.g. days in arrear in total)
        LWDecimal dec = new LWDecimal((Double)pObject);
        if (dec.getScale() == 0){
            pObject = dec.getJavaDecimal().toBigInteger();
        }
    }
    return formatObject(pObject);
}
```

My BIG Question is - guys, **how you handle all that hecking mess in BIRT number type system**?

Answer (score 1):

In BIRT API, they have this property definitions.

In general, if you are going to check the source code, in every "property" or "column" or "field" or whatever you call that object as long as it has properties that include its data type, you will notice that one of this object field is the string name of the data type. So it seems that the API verifies the selected data type by this string field.

For example, if you create a Output Column in DataSet and selected decimal as its data type,
the Display name in the drop down is actually in CamelCase which is "Decimal", but the XML name is "decimal".Doing this programmatically, you could try

```
 resultSetColumn.setDataType("Decimal");
```

So in this same way you can verify its exact type programmatically.

Below is the list of common data type for a DataSet column.

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/ref/rom/structs/ResultSetColumn.html#Property-dataType

UPDATE:
You could use DesignChoiceConstant's static constants, it includes the datatype available to BIRT.It also includes property names and values that you could use to other BIRT APIs such as css,labels, list of allowed values, etc.